# Best practice to read a list from aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

the situation is the following I have a pair of value/key constants I need to load in a dictionary in AWS lambda. They will be changed in future and more will be adding. So my question is: is there any best practice to do that. Hardcoding them in the code is just too ugly, database will be overkill as well as S3 file. I was thinking to record them as environmental variable.

Comment: Why do you think s3 is 'overkill'? - I can't think of a simpler or cheaper option than that.

Comment: I though for one file with couple values will be far too much.

Comment: A database would be overkill, I agree - but the nice thing about s3 is you can deploy changes to these values trivially easy just by uploading a new file.  I have used similar solutions in the past - sometimes simple is best. Of course there are lots of other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you going to have only one file with all the key/values pairs or one file per key/value pair? Also, why do you need them to be stored in files? Couldn't they just be loaded in memory (e.g. env vars) and stay in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Manager [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) is often a good default solution for storing smallish amounts of low turnover data for use in a Lambda function.

Parameter Store lets you store key-value pairs, optionally in a [hierarchy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-hierarchies.html).  Values are strings, string lists, or secure strings.  Parameters support labels and versions.

You'd use the [GetParametersByPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersByPath.html) API to read multiple nested parameters at once, simulating your list of key-value pairs.  For instance, you could return `fooValue`, `barValue` and `bazValue` by getting the `my-app/config/` path:

```
Parameter Name       Value
----------------     --------
my-app/config/foo     fooValue
my-app/config/bar     barValue 
my-app/config/baz     bazValue
```

Standard parameters are free to create and query.  Lambda has an optional [caching solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-the-aws-parameter-and-secrets-lambda-extension-to-cache-parameters-and-secrets/) for parameters.

You can use Parameters to store secrets, but Secrets Manager offers extra secrets-related functionality.

---

You have other reasonable choies. Serverless solutions like S3 or DynamoDB are in certain cases good, low-cost options to store arbitrary data for consumption by your Lambda functions.